# Add watermark using Jquery File Upload

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-file-upload

I'm using jquery file upload and I can't seem to figure out a way to add a watermark after the image has been uploaded.

http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to write some code on the server to altar the uploaded image with the watermark of your choice. Since you're using PHP, I'd suggest taking a look at ImageMagick since it should have what you're looking for, though any image manipulation library should be able to handle this simple task.

Comment: It's not belong to jQuery to add a (permanent) watermark. You have to use the server-side language. For example PHP you will find an running example here: sitepoint.com/watermark-images-php If you still want to create watermarks with CSS/HTML/Javascript you can use a set of html layers styled with css and javascript. But I guess that is NOT the wished solution.

Comment: i understand that. I'm just not sure where to add it to the existing code

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I had to find a solution and here is my example. So You need to modify **UploadHandler.php**, I did it in **function gd_create_scaled_image**

add:

```
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('../../img/stamp.png'); //path to your watermark file
$im = $src_func($file_path);
$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);
```

and:

```
$success = imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp)) && $write_func($im, $file_path, $image_quality)&& imagecopyresampled($new_img, $src_img, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $img_width, $img_height) && $write_func($new_img, $new_file_path, $image_quality);
$this->gd_set_image_object($file_path, $new_img);
return $success;
```

the whole function looks like this:

```
protected function gd_create_scaled_image($file_name, $version, $options) {
    if (!function_exists('imagecreatetruecolor')) {
        error_log('Function not found: imagecreatetruecolor');
        return false;
    }
    list($file_path, $new_file_path) =
        $this->get_scaled_image_file_paths($file_name, $version);
    $type = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file_name, '.'), 1));
    switch ($type) {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg':
            $src_func = 'imagecreatefromjpeg';
            $write_func = 'imagejpeg';
            $image_quality = isset($options['jpeg_quality']) ?
                $options['jpeg_quality'] : 75;
            break;
        case 'gif':
            $src_func = 'imagecreatefromgif';
            $write_func = 'imagegif';
            $image_quality = null;
            break;
        case 'png':
            $src_func = 'imagecreatefrompng';
            $write_func = 'imagepng';
            $image_quality = isset($options['png_quality']) ?
                $options['png_quality'] : 9;
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }

    //watermark
    $stamp = imagecreatefrompng('../../img/stamp.png'); //path to your watermark file
    $im = $src_func($file_path);
    $marge_right = 10;
    $marge_bottom = 10;
    $sx = imagesx($stamp);
    $sy = imagesy($stamp);

    $src_img = $this->gd_get_image_object(
        $file_path,
        $src_func,
        !empty($options['no_cache'])
    );
    $image_oriented = false;
    if (!empty($options['auto_orient']) && $this->gd_orient_image(
            $file_path,
            $src_img
        )) {
        $image_oriented = true;
        $src_img = $this->gd_get_image_object(
            $file_path,
            $src_func
        );
    }
    $max_width = $img_width = imagesx($src_img);
    $max_height = $img_height = imagesy($src_img);
    if (!empty($options['max_width'])) {
        $max_width = $options['max_width'];
    }
    if (!empty($options['max_height'])) {
        $max_height = $options['max_height'];
    }
    $scale = min(
        $max_width / $img_width,
        $max_height / $img_height
    );
    if ($scale >= 1) {
        if ($image_oriented) {
            return $write_func($src_img, $new_file_path, $image_quality);
        }
        if ($file_path !== $new_file_path) {
            return copy($file_path, $new_file_path);
        }
        return true;
    }
    if (empty($options['crop'])) {
        $new_width = $img_width * $scale;
        $new_height = $img_height * $scale;
        $dst_x = 0;
        $dst_y = 0;
        $new_img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    } else {
        if (($img_width / $img_height) >= ($max_width / $max_height)) {
            $new_width = $img_width / ($img_height / $max_height);
            $new_height = $max_height;
        } else {
            $new_width = $max_width;
            $new_height = $img_height / ($img_width / $max_width);
        }
        $dst_x = 0 - ($new_width - $max_width) / 2;
        $dst_y = 0 - ($new_height - $max_height) / 2;
        $new_img = imagecreatetruecolor($max_width, $max_height);
    }
    // Handle transparency in GIF and PNG images:
    switch ($type) {
        case 'gif':
        case 'png':
            imagecolortransparent($new_img, imagecolorallocate($new_img, 0, 0, 0));
        case 'png':
            imagealphablending($new_img, false);
            imagesavealpha($new_img, true);
            break;
    }
    //watermark
    $success = imagecopy(
        $im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp)
    ) && $write_func($im, $file_path, $image_quality)&& imagecopyresampled(
        $new_img, $src_img, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $img_width, $img_height
    ) && $write_func($new_img, $new_file_path, $image_quality);
    $this->gd_set_image_object($file_path, $new_img);
    return $success;
}
```

I hope this helps someone.

**EDIT:**

Also you have to force to use the GD library by changing in same file:

```
'image_library' => 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some code that does that in the `server/php/UploadHandler.php` file

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/UploadHandler.php

Answer (score 0):

I found this great tutorial to add watermark on uploaded image using ajax please follow along this link [Ajax file upload and watermark](http://www.vasplus.info/110.html).

You can make a separate function using the function code from the above link in the `UploadHandler` Class in `UploadHandler.php` file and use it as you desire. You can call this function immediately after the file gets uploaded.