# How can I add watermark while uploading images using blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I am using this plugin https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload to upload multiple images. I want to add watermark to these uploaded images.
I have read this. [Add watermark using Jquery File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393003/add-watermark-using-jquery-file-upload)

But, the solution is not working for me. Has anyone found any working solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I try that and it's OK. Please try again. Note that: It use GD library to handle image. So if you install imagick, please change option in this file to GD:
Search: image_library And change to 0

```
'image_library' => 1,
```